# Regex end of string wont work

Tags: regex

I want a REGEXP to use for mysql query.
I tried this regexp and use `.*` to mark anything between and the `$` to mark the end of the string.

```
Battlefield.*2$
```

and i get this result that is normal since "2" and "2142" are both ending in "2":

```
Battlefield 2
Battlefield :2
Battlefield: 2
Battlefield collection 2
Battlefield 2142
Battlefield : 2142
```

My target results is this:

```
Battlefield 2
Battlefield :2
Battlefield: 2
Battlefield collection 2
```

How can i get it?

Comment: Try `Battlefield.*\D2$`.

Comment: You need to buy Premium with a DLC pack for that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want any other digit before the 2, then you can use

```
Battlefield.*\D2$
```

Answer (score 3):

If the numbers aren't allowed, it should be:

```
Battlefield[^\d]+2$
```

Comment: This is much more restrictive. And `[^\d]` could be replaced with `\D`

Answer (score 0):

```
$string =~ m/Battlefield[ ]?[A-Za-z]*[ ]?[:]?[ ]?2$/)
```

Comment: As OP didn't precise a programming language (which is bad) you should probably only keep the regex part in your answer.